# Why the density will decrease?(Statistical Mechanics Entropy, Order Parameters And Complexity 2nd Edition)

Tags: statistical-mechanics, diffusion

Consider the diffusion equation in an external force $F$ and suppose $\rho$ is the density of a conserved quantity of the system(e.g. particle density), the diffusion equation is
$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = -\gamma F\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x} + D\frac{\partial^2 \rho}{\partial x^2}$$
and the current is
$$J = \gamma F\rho - D\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x}$$
(where $\gamma$ can be regarded as a positive constant)
then the book says that if $\rho$ is increasing in space and the force is dragging the particles($F$>zero) then $\rho$ will decrease with time because the high-density regions ahead of $x$ are receding and the low-density regions behind $x$ are moving in.

Formally, I wonder how can this be hold since the diffusion equation can be written as
$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = -\frac{\partial J}{\partial x}$$
but the condition that $\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x}$ and $F$ are both greater than zero doesn't necessarily yield $\frac{\partial J}{\partial x}$ > zero.

Comment: You cannot have, in one statement, that $\rho$ is both increasing and decreasing. Please review your question.

Comment: I think the statement in the book is a stupid tautology. If you neglect the $\partial^2_x\rho$ term, then just by reading the equation you can see the $\gamma>0\ \bigwedge\ F>0\ \bigwedge\ \partial_x\rho>0\implies\partial_t\rho<0$

Comment: Yeah, you are right and from the context, it seems that the book is actually talking about the sign of the first term in the diffusion equation.